# 'an illegal memory access' when trying to write to a 2D array allocated using cudaMalloc3D

Tags: c, cuda

I am trying to allocate and copy memory of a flattened 2D array on to the device using cudaMalloc3D to test the performance of cudaMalloc3D. But when I try to write to the array from the kernel it throws 'an illegal memory access was encountered' exception. The program runs fine if I am just reading from the array but when I try to write to it, there is an error. Any help on this will be greatly appreciated. Below is my code and the syntax for compiling the code.

Compile using

```
nvcc -O2 -arch sm_20 test.cu
```

Code: test.cu

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.14159265 
#define NX 8192     /* includes boundary points on both end */
#define NY 4096     /* includes boundary points on both end */
#define NZ 1        /* needed for cudaMalloc3D */

#define N_THREADS_X 16
#define N_THREADS_Y 16
#define N_BLOCKS_X NX/N_THREADS_X 
#define N_BLOCKS_Y NY/N_THREADS_Y 

#define LX 4.0    /* length of the domain in x-direction  */
#define LY 2.0    /* length of the domain in x-direction  */
#define dx       (REAL) ( LX/( (REAL) (NX) ) )
#define cSqrd     5.0
#define dt       (REAL) ( 0.4 * dx / sqrt(cSqrd) )
#define FACTOR   ( cSqrd * (dt*dt)/(dx*dx) )

#define IC  (i + j*NX)       /* (i,j)   */
#define IM1 (i + j*NX - 1)   /* (i-1,j) */
#define IP1 (i + j*NX + 1)   /* (i+1,j) */
#define JM1 (i + (j-1)*NX)   /* (i,j-1) */
#define JP1 (i + (j+1)*NX)   /* (i,j+1) */


// Macro for checking CUDA errors following a CUDA launch or API call
#define cudaCheckError() {\
  cudaError_t e = cudaGetLastError();\
  if( e != cudaSuccess ) {\
    printf("\nCuda failure %s:%d: '%s'\n",__FILE__,__LINE__,cudaGetErrorString(e));\
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);\
  }\
}

typedef double REAL;
typedef int    INT;


void meshGrid ( REAL *x, REAL *y )
{

  INT i,j;
  REAL a;
  for (j=0; j<NY; j++) {
    a = dx * ( (REAL) j );
    for (i=0; i<NX; i++) {
      x[IC] =  dx * ( (REAL) i );
      y[IC] = a;
    }
  }
}


void initWave ( REAL *u, REAL *uold, REAL *x, REAL *y )
{                    
  INT i,j;
  for (j=1; j<NY-1; j++) {
    for (i=1; i<NX-1; i++) {
      u[IC] =  0.1 * (4.0*x[IC]-x[IC]*x[IC]) * ( 2.0*y[IC] - y[IC]*y[IC] );
    }
  }

  for (j=1; j<NY-1; j++) {
    for (i=1; i<NX-1; i++) {
      uold[IC] = u[IC] + 0.5*FACTOR*( u[IP1] + u[IM1] + u[JP1] + u[JM1] - 4.0*u[IC] );
    }
  }
}


__global__ void solveWaveGPU ( cudaPitchedPtr uold, cudaPitchedPtr u, cudaPitchedPtr unew )
{

 INT i,j;

 i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
 j = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

 if (i>0 && i < (NX-1) && j>0 && j < (NY-1) ) {

  char *unewPtr  = (char *) unew.ptr;
  REAL *unew_row = (REAL *) (unewPtr + i * unew.pitch);

  REAL tmp = unew_row[j]; // no error on this line
  unew_row[j] = 1.2; // this is where I get the error
 }

}


INT main(INT argc, char *argv[])
{

  INT nTimeSteps = 10;  

  // pointers for the host side
  REAL *unew, *u, *uold, *uFinal, *x, *y;

  // allocate memory on the host
  unew        = (REAL *)calloc(NX*NY,sizeof(REAL));
  u           = (REAL *)calloc(NX*NY,sizeof(REAL));
  uold        = (REAL *)calloc(NX*NY,sizeof(REAL));
  uFinal      = (REAL *)calloc(NX*NY,sizeof(REAL));
  x           = (REAL *)calloc(NX*NY,sizeof(REAL));
  y           = (REAL *)calloc(NX*NY,sizeof(REAL));


  // pointer for the device side
  size_t pitch = NX * sizeof(REAL);
  cudaPitchedPtr  d_u, d_uold, d_unew, d_tmp;
  cudaExtent myExtent = make_cudaExtent(pitch, NY, NZ);

  // allocate 3D memory on the device
  cudaMalloc3D( &d_u, myExtent );    cudaCheckError();
  cudaMalloc3D( &d_uold, myExtent ); cudaCheckError();
  cudaMalloc3D( &d_unew, myExtent ); cudaCheckError();


  // initialize grid and wave
  meshGrid( x, y );
  initWave( u, uold, x, y );


  // copy host memory to 3D device memory
  cudaMemcpy3DParms cpy3D = { 0 };
  cpy3D.kind = cudaMemcpyHostToDevice;

  // copying u to d_u
  cpy3D.srcPtr = make_cudaPitchedPtr(u, pitch, NX, NY);
  cpy3D.dstPtr = d_u;
  cpy3D.extent = myExtent;
  cudaMemcpy3D( &cpy3D ); cudaCheckError();  

  // copying uold to d_uold
  cpy3D.srcPtr = make_cudaPitchedPtr(uold, pitch, NX, NY);
  cpy3D.dstPtr = d_uold;
  cpy3D.extent = myExtent;
  cudaMemcpy3D( &cpy3D ); cudaCheckError();  


  //  set up the GPU grid/block model
  dim3 dimGrid  ( N_BLOCKS_X , N_BLOCKS_Y  );
  dim3 dimBlock ( N_THREADS_X, N_THREADS_Y );

  for ( INT n = 1; n < nTimeSteps + 1; n++ ) {
    solveWaveGPU <<< dimGrid, dimBlock >>> ( d_uold, d_u, d_unew );
    cudaThreadSynchronize();
    cudaCheckError();

    d_tmp  = d_uold;
    d_uold = d_u;
    d_u    = d_unew;
    d_unew = d_tmp;
  }

  // copy the memory back to host
  cpy3D.kind = cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost;

  // copying d_unew to uFinal
  cpy3D.srcPtr = d_unew;
  cpy3D.dstPtr = make_cudaPitchedPtr(uFinal, pitch, NX, NY);
  cpy3D.extent = myExtent;
  cudaMemcpy3D( &cpy3D ); cudaCheckError();  

  free(u);    cudaFree(d_u.ptr);
  free(unew); cudaFree(d_unew.ptr);
  free(uold); cudaFree(d_uold.ptr);

  free(uFinal); free(x); free(y);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the error doesn't occur on this line:

```
REAL tmp = unew_row[j]; // no error on this line
```

is because the compiler is optimizing that line out.  It doesn't do anything useful, and so the compiler completely eliminates it.  The compiler warning:

```
xxx.cu(87): warning: variable "tmp" was declared but never referenced
```

is a hint to that effect.

Your code is very nearly correct.  The issue is here:

```
REAL *unew_row = (REAL *) (unewPtr + i * unew.pitch);
```

It should be:

```
REAL *unew_row = (REAL *) (unewPtr + j * unew.pitch);
```

The `i` variable in your kernel is the *width* (i.e. X) dimension.
The `j` variable is the *height* (i.e. Y) dimension.

The height is the one that refers to which row you are on, therefore the row pitch should be multiplied by the height parameter, i.e. `j`, not `i`.

Similarly, although it's not the source of the specific failure for your particular dimensions, this code may be not what you intended either:

```
REAL tmp = unew_row[j]; // no error on this line
unew_row[j] = 1.2; // this is where I get the error
```

If, for example, you were intending to compute the offset to the row and then index into the row (perhaps to set every element in the alocation, for example) then I think you would want to use `i` not `j` as your final index:

```
REAL tmp = unew_row[i]; // no error on this line
unew_row[i] = 1.2; // this is where I get the error
```

However, for this particular example, this is not the actual source of the illegal memory access.

Comment: Thank you @robert that fixed my issue. I ran the two versions of the same code using cudaMalloc3D and the other with just cudaMalloc. I found cudaMalloc3D to be slower and I was thinking it should have been faster. If you have any thoughts on that could you care to share it.

Comment: I would probably need to see both versions and see what exactly you are timing.   If it's just the kernel you are timing, I wouldn't expect much difference.  This kernel should be memory bandwidth bound.    Note that consistent with the mixup of `i` vs. `j` as mentioned in my answer, I would suggest that there is a mixup in the kernel code as well.  I would instead expect e.g. `unew_row[i] = 1.2;` (using `i` not `j`), assuming you were trying to set every value in the allocation.     Otherwise, I would suggest posting a new question if you want help there.

Comment: Hmm, would you mind taking a look at them, I setup a github repo where i put the two files and here is a link to the repo: [github-repo](https://github.com/anup-boisestate/cuda_test) I can also post another question if it would be better. Thanks

Comment: Please post another question.

Comment: I have posted another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30903380/cudamalloc-vs-cudamalloc3d-performance-for-a-2d-array