# cudaMalloc vs cudaMalloc3D performance for a 2D array

Tags: c, cuda

I want to know the impact on performance when using cudaMalloc or cudaMalloc3D when allocating, copying and accessing memory for a 2D array. I have code that I tried to test the run time on where on one I use cudaMalloc and on the other cudaMalloc3D. I have included the code below. An explanation on how the performance is impacted by either api would be much appreciated.

cudaMalloc code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.14159265
#define NX 8192     /* includes boundary points on both end */
#define NY 4096     /* includes boundary points on both end */

#define N_THREADS_X 16
#define N_THREADS_Y 16
#define N_BLOCKS_X NX/N_THREADS_X 
#define N_BLOCKS_Y NY/N_THREADS_Y 

#define LX 4.0    /* length of the domain in x-direction  */
#define LY 2.0    /* length of the domain in x-direction  */
#define dx       (REAL) ( LX/( (REAL) (NX) ) )
#define cSqrd     5.0
#define dt       (REAL) ( 0.4 * dx / sqrt(cSqrd) )
#define FACTOR   ( cSqrd * (dt*dt)/(dx*dx) )

#define IC  (i + j*NX)       /* (i,j)   */
#define IM1 (i + j*NX - 1)   /* (i-1,j) */
#define IP1 (i + j*NX + 1)   /* (i+1,j) */
#define JM1 (i + (j-1)*NX)   /* (i,j-1) */
#define JP1 (i + (j+1)*NX)   /* (i,j+1) */


#define cudaCheckError() {\
  cudaError_t e = cudaGetLastError() ; \
  if( e != cudaSuccess ) {\
    printf("\nCuda Failure %s:%d: %s\n",__FILE__,__LINE__,cudaGetErrorString(e));\
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);\
  }\
}

typedef double REAL;
typedef int    INT;                

__global__ void solveWaveGPU ( REAL *uold, REAL *u, REAL *unew )
{

 INT i,j;

 i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
 j = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

 if (i>0 && i < (NX-1) && j>0 && j < (NY-1) ) {

    unew[IC] = 2.0*u[IC] - uold[IC] + FACTOR*( u[IP1] + u[IM1] + u[JP1] + u[JM1] - 4.0*u[IC] );

 }
} 

void initWave ( REAL *unew, REAL *u, REAL *uold, REAL *x, REAL *y )
{                    

    INT i,j;

    for (j=1; j<NY-1; j++) {
        for (i=1; i<NX-1; i++) {
            u[IC] =  0.1 * (4.0*x[IC]-x[IC]*x[IC]) * ( 2.0*y[IC] - y[IC]*y[IC] );
        }
    }
    for (j=1; j<NY-1; j++) {
        for (i=1; i<NX-1; i++) {
            uold[IC] = u[IC] + 0.5*FACTOR*( u[IP1] + u[IM1] + u[JP1] + u[JM1] - 4.0*u[IC] );
        }
    }
}

void meshGrid ( REAL *x, REAL *y )
{

    INT i,j;
    REAL a;

    for (j=0; j<NY; j++) {
        a = dx * ( (REAL) j );
        for (i=0; i<NX; i++) {
            x[IC] =  dx * ( (REAL) i );
            y[IC] = a;
        }
     }
}

INT main(INT argc, char *argv[])
{ 

    INT nTimeSteps = 100;

    REAL *unew,   *u,   *uold,   *uFinal, *x, *y; //pointers for the host side
    REAL *d_unew, *d_u, *d_uold, *tmp;                 //pointers for the device

//  variable declaration for timing
    cudaEvent_t timeStart, timeStop;
    cudaEventCreate(&timeStart);
    cudaEventCreate(&timeStop);
    float elapsedTime_gpu;

    unew           = (REAL *)calloc(NX*NY,sizeof(REAL));
    u              = (REAL *)calloc(NX*NY,sizeof(REAL));
    uold           = (REAL *)calloc(NX*NY,sizeof(REAL));
    uFinal         = (REAL *)calloc(NX*NY,sizeof(REAL));
    x              = (REAL *)calloc(NX*NY,sizeof(REAL));
    y              = (REAL *)calloc(NX*NY,sizeof(REAL));

// create device copies of the variables

    cudaMalloc( (void**) &d_unew,  NX*NY*sizeof(REAL) ); cudaCheckError(); 
    cudaMalloc( (void**) &d_u,     NX*NY*sizeof(REAL) ); cudaCheckError();
    cudaMalloc( (void**) &d_uold,  NX*NY*sizeof(REAL) ); cudaCheckError();

    meshGrid( x, y );
    initWave( unew, u, uold, x, y );

//  start timing the GPU

    cudaMemcpy( d_u, u,       NX*NY*sizeof(REAL), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice ); cudaCheckError();
    cudaMemcpy( d_uold, uold, NX*NY*sizeof(REAL), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice ); cudaCheckError();
    cudaMemcpy( d_unew, unew, NX*NY*sizeof(REAL), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice ); cudaCheckError();

//  set up the GPU grid/block model

    dim3 dimGrid  ( N_BLOCKS_X , N_BLOCKS_Y  );
    dim3 dimBlock ( N_THREADS_X, N_THREADS_Y );  

//  launch the GPU kernel

    cudaEventRecord(timeStart, 0);

    for (INT n=1; n<nTimeSteps+1; n++) {

       solveWaveGPU <<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(d_uold, d_u, d_unew);
       cudaDeviceSynchronize();
       cudaCheckError();

       tmp    = d_uold;
       d_uold = d_u;
       d_u    = d_unew;
       d_unew = tmp;

    }
    cudaEventRecord(timeStop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(timeStop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedTime_gpu, timeStart, timeStop);

    cudaMemcpy( uFinal, d_u, NX*NY*sizeof(REAL), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost ); cudaCheckError();

    printf("elapsedTime on the GPU= %f s.\n", elapsedTime_gpu/1000.0);

    free(unew);       free(u);       free(uold);
    cudaFree(d_unew); cudaFree(d_u); cudaFree(d_uold);
    free(uFinal); free(x); free(y);

    cudaEventDestroy(timeStart);
    cudaEventDestroy(timeStop);

    return (0);
}
```

cudaMalloc3D code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.14159265
#define NX 8192     /* includes boundary points on both end */
#define NY 4096     /* includes boundary points on both end */
#define NZ 1        /* needed for cudaMalloc3D */

#define N_THREADS_X 16
#define N_THREADS_Y 16
#define N_BLOCKS_X NX/N_THREADS_X 
#define N_BLOCKS_Y NY/N_THREADS_Y 

#define LX 4.0    /* length of the domain in x-direction  */
#define LY 2.0    /* length of the domain in x-direction  */
#define dx       (REAL) ( LX/( (REAL) (NX) ) )
#define cSqrd     5.0
#define dt       (REAL) ( 0.4 * dx / sqrt(cSqrd) )
#define FACTOR   ( cSqrd * (dt*dt)/(dx*dx) )

#define IC  (i + j*NX)       /* (i,j)   */
#define IM1 (i + j*NX - 1)   /* (i-1,j) */
#define IP1 (i + j*NX + 1)   /* (i+1,j) */
#define JM1 (i + (j-1)*NX)   /* (i,j-1) */
#define JP1 (i + (j+1)*NX)   /* (i,j+1) */

#define cudaCheckError() {\
  cudaError_t e = cudaGetLastError() ; \
  if( e != cudaSuccess ) {\
    printf("\nCuda Failure %s:%d: %s\n",__FILE__,__LINE__,cudaGetErrorString(e));\
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);\
  }\
}

typedef double REAL;
typedef int    INT;


__global__ void solveWaveGPU ( cudaPitchedPtr uold, cudaPitchedPtr u, cudaPitchedPtr unew )
{

 INT i,j;

 i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
 j = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

 if (i>0 && i < (NX-1) && j>0 && j < (NY-1) ) {

    char *d_u    = (char *) u.ptr;
    char *d_uold = (char *) uold.ptr;
    char *d_unew = (char *) unew.ptr;

    REAL *u_row = (REAL *)(d_u + j * u.pitch);
    REAL u_IP1  = ( (REAL *)(d_u + (j+1) * u.pitch) )[i];
    REAL u_IM1  = ( (REAL *)(d_u + (j-1) * u.pitch) )[i];
    REAL u_JP1  = u_row[i+1];
    REAL u_JM1  = u_row[i-1];
    REAL u_IC   = u_row[i];

    REAL uold_IC  = ( (REAL *)(d_uold + j * uold.pitch) )[i];
    REAL *unew_row = (REAL *)(d_unew + j * unew.pitch);

    unew_row[i] = 2.0 * u_IC - uold_IC + FACTOR * ( u_IP1 + u_IM1 + u_JP1 + u_JM1 - 4.0 * u_IC );

 }

}                  

void initWave ( REAL *unew, REAL *u, REAL *uold, REAL *x, REAL *y )
{                    

    INT i,j;

    for (j=1; j<NY-1; j++) {
        for (i=1; i<NX-1; i++) {
            u[IC] =  0.1 * (4.0*x[IC]-x[IC]*x[IC]) * ( 2.0*y[IC] - y[IC]*y[IC] );
        }
    }
    for (j=1; j<NY-1; j++) {
        for (i=1; i<NX-1; i++) {
            uold[IC] = u[IC] + 0.5*FACTOR*( u[IP1] + u[IM1] + u[JP1] + u[JM1] - 4.0*u[IC] );
        }
    }
}

void meshGrid ( REAL *x, REAL *y )
{

    INT i,j;
    REAL a;

    for (j=0; j<NY; j++) {
        a = dx * ( (REAL) j );
        for (i=0; i<NX; i++) {
            x[IC] =  dx * ( (REAL) i );
            y[IC] = a;
        }
     }
}

INT main(INT argc, char *argv[])
{
    INT nTimeSteps = 100;
    REAL *unew, *u, *uold, *uFinal, *x, *y; //pointers for the host side

//  variable declaration for timing    
    cudaEvent_t timeStart, timeStop;
    cudaEventCreate(&timeStart);
    cudaEventCreate(&timeStop);
    float elapsedTime_gpu;

    unew           = (REAL *)calloc(NX*NY,sizeof(REAL));
    u              = (REAL *)calloc(NX*NY,sizeof(REAL));
    uold           = (REAL *)calloc(NX*NY,sizeof(REAL));
    uFinal         = (REAL *)calloc(NX*NY,sizeof(REAL));
    x              = (REAL *)calloc(NX*NY,sizeof(REAL));
    y              = (REAL *)calloc(NX*NY,sizeof(REAL));


    cudaExtent myExtent = make_cudaExtent(NX * sizeof(REAL), NY, NZ);
    cudaPitchedPtr d_u, d_uold, d_unew, d_tmp;

    // create device copies of the variables
    cudaMalloc3D( &d_u   , myExtent );   cudaCheckError();
    cudaMalloc3D( &d_uold, myExtent );   cudaCheckError();
    cudaMalloc3D( &d_unew, myExtent );   cudaCheckError();

    meshGrid( x, y );
    initWave( unew, u, uold, x, y );

    cudaMemcpy3DParms cpy3D = { 0 };
    cpy3D.extent = myExtent;
    cpy3D.kind   = cudaMemcpyHostToDevice;

    // copy 3D from u to d_u
    cpy3D.srcPtr = make_cudaPitchedPtr(u, NX*sizeof(REAL), NX, NY);
    cpy3D.dstPtr = d_u;
    cudaMemcpy3D( &cpy3D ); cudaCheckError();

    // copy 3D from uold to d_uold
    cpy3D.srcPtr = make_cudaPitchedPtr(uold, NX*sizeof(REAL), NX, NY);
    cpy3D.dstPtr = d_uold;
    cudaMemcpy3D( &cpy3D ); cudaCheckError();

    //  set up the GPU grid/block model
    dim3 dimGrid  ( N_BLOCKS_X , N_BLOCKS_Y  );
    dim3 dimBlock ( N_THREADS_X, N_THREADS_Y );  

    //  launch the GPU kernel
    //  start timing the GPU
    cudaEventRecord(timeStart, 0);

    for (INT n=1; n<nTimeSteps+1; n++) {

       solveWaveGPU <<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(d_uold, d_u, d_unew);
       cudaDeviceSynchronize();
       cudaCheckError();

       d_tmp  = d_uold;
       d_uold = d_u;
       d_u    = d_unew;
       d_unew = d_tmp;

    }
    cudaEventRecord(timeStop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(timeStop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedTime_gpu, timeStart, timeStop);


    // copy 3D from d_u to uFinal
    cpy3D.kind   = cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost;
    cpy3D.srcPtr = d_u;
    cpy3D.dstPtr = make_cudaPitchedPtr(uFinal, NX*sizeof(REAL), NX, NY);
    cudaMemcpy3D( &cpy3D ); cudaCheckError();

    printf("elapsedTime on the GPU= %f s.\n", elapsedTime_gpu/1000.0);

    free(u);    cudaFree(d_unew.ptr);
    free(uold); cudaFree(d_u.ptr);
    free(unew); cudaFree(d_uold.ptr);
    free(uFinal); free(x); free(y);

    cudaEventDestroy(timeStart);
    cudaEventDestroy(timeStop);

    return (0);
}
```

Timing:

```
cudaMalloc3D: 1.192510 s
cudaMalloc:   0.960322 s
```

Machine specification:

```
GNU/Linux x86_64
NVIDIA GeForce GTX Titan CC: 3.5
CUDA ver 7.0
```

Comment: I suggest posting your code in the question, not in an external github repo.  You should also define how you are taking the timing measurement if it's not evident from the code, and give the exact timing results, as well as the machine specification:  CPU, GPU, OS, CUDA version.

Comment: On a sm_30 equipped linux machine, I measure the `cudaMalloc3d` version to be about 10% *slower* than the `cudaMalloc` version (0.945 seconds average versus 0.812 seconds for an average of 5 program runs).

Comment: `cudaMalloc` takes 1.002985 seconds and `cudaMalloc3d` takes 1.286137 on a GTX TITAN with CUDA `ver 5.5`

Comment: I measure the `cudaMalloc3D` version to be slower also, and I believe OP thinks it is slower also based on comments below [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30898815/an-illegal-memory-access-when-trying-to-write-to-a-2d-array-allocated-using-cu/30900357#30900357).  The reporting in this question is probably a typo.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: This is an interesting example, if only because it uncovers a *huge* performance regression between CUDA 7 and CUDA 6.x. The CUDA 7 compiler does something incredibly dumb and directly inlines the computation for `dt` rather than computing it at compile time like the CUDA 6.x compilers do. That is a factor of 2 performance loss between compilers on these kernels. But I guess the speed difference between the two kernels is just down to increased overhead for the array indexing calculations in the pitched memory version

Comment: Yes, I believe the speed difference is due to increased overhead.  I did profiling and confirmed there were no changes in memory load efficiency or memory store efficiency, but dumping the sass yielded about ~250 instructions for the faster kernel and ~300 instructions for the slower kernel.  Thanks for the pointer on CUDA 6.5 vs. CUDA 7, I had been testing with CUDA 7 only.  I'll take a look at CUDA 6.5 and if I can confirm your observation I'll file a bug.  Thanks.

Comment: I am so sorry guys, I switched the timings I get cudaMalloc3D to be slower too.

Comment: So, does that mean it is better to use strided access to memory than use pitched memory for a 2D array or is it true just for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The performance difference you observe is mostly due to the increased instruction overhead in the pitched memory indexing scheme. Because your array size is a large power of two in the major direction, it is very likely that the pitched array allocated with `cudaMalloc3D` is the same size as the naïve allocation using `cudaMalloc`. You may find that the performance difference between the two versions changes if you vary the problem size.

(Take note of the comments regarding compiler regressions in CUDA 7. If you refactor your code to pass the Fourier number as a kernel parameter, you will probably get a far bigger performance change than any difference due to pitched memory).